# Inheritance in Class

Tags: vb.net, oop

Question #1: Does this look like the proper way to use inheritance in my class? I plan to add methods to the PartPnl so that both RoughPnl and FinalPnl can use together by using their objects specific data.

Question #2: Using the default values in the properties seems like the best way to get values to my object from my main form. Is that the best way to do that or is there a different approach? The main form will be open the entire time but the object will only exist long enough to do what I need, like create RoughPnl->Use a Method or two->Add Panel to form->Done

```
Namespace PanelThings
Public Class PartPnl

    Private TrvList As TreeView
    Private BasePanel As Panel
    Private Label As String = Main.cboLabel.Text
    Private Qty As String = Main.cboQty.Text
    Private Key As String = Nothing
    Private HorizontalON As Boolean = Main.chkHorizontal.Checked
    Private VerticalON As Boolean = Main.chkVertical.Checked
    Private ScaleToPanelON As Boolean = Main.chkScaleToPanel.Checked
    Private Scale As String = Main.cboScale.Text
    Private RearrangeON As Boolean = Main.chkRearrange.Checked

    Public Sub New(objTree As TreeView, basePanel As Panel)
        TrvList = objTree
        basePanel = basePanel
    End Sub
End Class


Public Class FinalPnl
    Inherits PartPnl

    Private FinalWidth As String = Main.cboWidth.Text
    Private FinalLength As String = Main.cboLength.Text
    Private FinalColor As String = Main.picFinalColor.Tag
    Private LabelON As Boolean = Main.chkLabelsON.Checked
    Private SizeON As Boolean = Main.chkSizeON.Checked

    Private PorSKey As String = "P"
    Public Sub New(objTree As TreeView, basePanel As Panel)
        MyBase.New(objTree, basePanel)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class RoughPnl
    Inherits FinalPnl

    Private RoughWidth As String = Main.cboWidthExtra.Text
    Private RoughLength As String = Main.cboLengthExtra.Text
    Private RoughColor As String = Main.picRoughColor.Tag
    Private RoughON As Boolean = Main.chkRoughUnderFinal.Checked

    Public Sub New(objTree As TreeView, basePanel As Panel)
        MyBase.New(objTree, basePanel)
    End Sub
End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: From design point of view I see nothing wrong. It is perfectly valid. For your case ... 1: Might be helpful to declare `Protected` `PartPnl.TrvList`  and  `PartPnl.BasePanel`. 2: What is Main? Maybe a better approach is to be member of `PartPnl` to avoid direct reference in inherited classes.

Comment: It is almost always a bad idea to reference some other control/object in the initialization code.  As is, those not only assume there is something called main (apparently a form) somewhere, but that it also already includes a number of valid instances of things with specific names.  There is also no sign of this being a control, or inheriting from `Panel` if that was the intent

Comment: @shadow: Main is my "form1" of my application. Make it a member you are saying nest the classes within the PartPnl class. That makes since! Thanks!

Comment: @Plutonix: So my object will be using a method to create an actual Panel control called MyPanel which basically is an inherited panel with a border. When I run my code I will put in the panels dimensions and and a few other properties and then click button called "Add" in which my object will be created and take all those values and create a new "MyPanel" control that will be added to the Main Form. I originally did this all successfully in a procedural approach, but I think this could simplify the code.